# DNS settings shared between Route53 and previous hosting provider

Tags: dns, dns-servers, route53

We have a company website at `www.example.com` and `example.com` which is hosted at a hosting provider - The NS records here are for the providers name server.

Our API is accessible at `api.example.com` - this DNS is part of a hosted zone (not a registered domain) on Route53 and it points to a Load Balancer on AWS - The NS records here are AWS's.

I recently inherited this platform and need to add a new record. I can't seem to find the relationship between our registered domain name (at the hosting provider) and our route53 service. I initially thought the NS records at our hosting provider are updated to cater for AWS according to their docs here:
https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/

> If your domain name is not managed by Route 53, you will need to
>   inform the registrar with whom you registered your domain name to
>   update the name servers for your domain to the ones associated with
>   your hosted zone. If your domain name is managed by Route 53 already,
>   your domain name will be automatically associated with the name
>   servers hosting your zone.

As I mentioned however, the NS records at the hosting provider is their own. Where else can I start looking for the link between our provider and Route 53?

Comment: Giving the domain name concerned always help getting more accurate answers... Otherwise a simple `dig` query should show you which nameservers are currently authoritative for your domain and hence any DNS settings will need to happen on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should mean that there are NS records for your subdomain at your main DNS host.  Your DNS heirarchy should look like:

- Domain registrar: `NS` records for `example.com` to main DNS host

  - Main DNS Host:

    - `A` record for `example.com`
    - `A` or `CNAME` record for `www.example.com`
    - `NS` records for `api.example.com` to route53

      - Route53: `ALIAS` records for `api.example.com` to the load balancer

You can verify this by using `dig` on the command line which should show you the various records.   Particularly, you want to see the NS records for `api.example.com`:

```
dig NS api.example.com
```